# Move Repetitive list Data to Table

Tags: python, pandas

How do I go from this dataframe:

```
Name  Ken
Age   20
Sex   M
Name  Mary
Age   34
Sex   F
```

to this:

```
Name  Age   Sex
Ken   20    M
Mary  34    F
```

????

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that easily. Your data is structured 'json like', so if that's the case, there is `.read_json`. If not I'd consider either converting your data to a proper `json` or to desired format before loading it into `dataframe`.

Answer (score 1):

Pivot the dataframe, forward fill and drop the null rows in the Sex column

```
     0       1
0   Name    Ken
1   Age     20
2   Sex     M
3   Name    Mary
4   Age     34
5   Sex     F

(df.pivot(columns=0,values=1)
 .assign(Name = lambda x: x.Name.ffill(),
         Age = lambda x: x.Age.ffill()
    )
 .dropna(subset=['Sex'])
)

    Age Name    Sex
2   20  Ken     M
5   34  Mary    F
```

Answer (score 0):

One more approach

```
s = df.index//3
df_new = pd.concat([y.reset_index(drop=True) for x , y in df['B'].groupby(s)],axis=1).T.reset_index(drop=True)
df_new.columns = ['Name', 'Age','Sex']
df_new
```

**Output**

```
   Name     Age Sex
0   Ken     20  M
1   Mary    34  F
```